# Something causing skewed results in basic SQL query via PHP

Tags: php, mysql

When I run the query below I am getting really skewed results, but when I run the query in phpmyadmin the results are fine, so I am doing something wrong in PHP. If anyone could point it out I would be really grateful!

```
    $lecturers = array ('A1', 'A2', 'A3');
        $baseindex = 0;



        $temparray1 = array ( );
        $i = 0;
   $q7 = "SELECT `groupid` FROM `groups` WHERE `uninum` = '".$lecturers [$baseindex]."'";
        $result7 = @mysqli_query($dbcon,$q7);
        while ($row7 = mysqli_fetch_array ($result7, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            $temparray1 = $row7['groupid']; 

            $temparray1[$i] = $row7['groupid'];
            echo $temparray1 [$i] . "<BR><BR>";
            $i++;
        }
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know what "skew" you are seeing.

Comment: a sample of what the result is and what result you expecting would help us - helping you.

Comment: The result I am getting is 1, 1, 2, 3, but it should be 1, 15, 29, 36

Comment: So the result doesn't match with the database. Also the database wouldn't have duplicate values ie (groupid) for a single 'uninum' (a single person)

Comment: slightly offtopic: `$result7`, `$q7` and the actual "error" (the wrong, duplicate assignment) plus the bonus "assign to array to just immediately print that one element" ...it all indiciates that you should progress a bit more slowly, understand the principles and structure your affords (and in consequence the script) a bit more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the line

```
$temparray1 = $row7['groupid'];
```

I guess that one breaks your array.

Comment: Thanks so much Philipp! That was it:).

Comment: Please consider marking this as the correct answer. ;)